# How do I debug an exe running through Windows Scheduler?

Tags: debugging, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using Windows Scheduler to run an exe I have written.

How can I jump into a debug session when the scheduler starts my exe?

**Update 1.** 
I had thought of doing a Thread.Sleep and then Attach to Process. When I tried it, it says Debugger is already attached to process...

Answer (score 5):

You could just call **DebugBreak()** from within your program.

According to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297(VS.85).aspx), DebugBreak does the following:

> Causes a breakpoint exception to occur
>   in the current process. This allows
>   the calling thread to signal the
>   debugger to handle the exception.
>
> To cause a breakpoint exception in
>   another process, use the
>   DebugBreakProcess function.

You can then attach your debugger at this point, and continue running the program.

The only problem with this solution is that you need to make the DebugBreak() in the code conditional, so that it won't break *every* time the program is run.  Maybe you achieve this through an environment variable, registry setting, or a parameter which the scheduler passes in to the program to ensure that it breaks when it starts up.

#### Example code

Here's some untested example code reading an environment variable:

```
int main()
{
    char *debugBreakChar = getenv("DEBUG_BREAK");
    int debugBreak = atoi(debugBreakChar);
    if (debugBreak)
    {
        DebugBreak();
    }

    // Rest of the program follows here
}
```

Now all you need to do is set the environment variable as a system variable, and ensure that it's accessible from the same shell context as the scheduler (rebooting will achieve this):

```
set DEBUG_BREAK=1
```

Now the program will break on startup, allowing you to attach a debugger.  Changing the environment variable to 0, or un-setting it, will allow the program to run normally.

Environment variables are a bit fiddly in this regard, as they are context-based and you need to know that the scheduler runs from the same environmental context.  Registry values are better than this, and you can read a registry value using [RegQueryValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(VS.85).aspx) in your code instead (you'll need to include windows.h to use this function).

Comment: I followed the link, but not sure how to implement that... could you give a code example? NB. the exe is a C# Console App

Comment: The C# version is System.Diagnostics.Debug.Break()

Comment: thanks for the answer... but I was looking for the C# version in the accepted answer.. you got an upvote though!

Comment: I probably shouldn't have assumed you wanted a C++ answer.  Next time it might be worth including your language of choice as a tag :-)

Answer (score 2):

Attach to Process will work (from within Visual Studio), although you may need to add a sleep statement at the beginning of your code if it is a fast process so that you can attach before it starts your main logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` that will attach debugger to the process when the process is launched. You can read how to do this in this [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=238788).

There are couple of gotchas with this approach:

- [IFEO debugging does not work with pure managed debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2006/02/16/ifeo_managed_debugging.aspx). You need to use [Interop Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/2005/01/28/362169.aspx)
- You might need to remote your debugger to another session, depending on what user the Scheduler launches your app as.

To debug using VS, you need to actually specifyg **VSJitDebugger.exe** in the IFEO options for your executable. You will also have to specify the debugging engine to use manually. [More details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

"Attach to Process" in Visual Studio's Debug menu.