# win task scheduler fails to run an exe

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

I have an exe file which runs OK when I double clik on it (even when not Admin mode)

When I run it through win-task-scheduler it fails right at the start.

(I see it fails on configuring Nhibernate)

1) How can I configure the scheduler to run in elevated mode?

2) If that doesn't help - any other idea?

[image]

Comment: You cut out the most important part of the error.  The stack trace doesn't tell us much.  Elevated mode?  No.  You need to figure out 1) what rights your executable requires in order to run and then 2) provide those specific rights to the account that is executing your application.  Don't use a shotgun to drive a nail.

Comment: I've found that if the error message doesn't tell you the problem, the event log usually does in cases like this (running from a scheduled task, windows service, etc.)

Comment: @Will didn't cut, that's all I can see. It's forzen. How can I give specific rights?

Comment: You could try to run the debugger from the program while it runs under the scheduler, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588946/how-do-i-debug-an-exe-running-through-windows-scheduler

Comment: I think you can run a scheduled task elevated by using the "Run with highest privileges" checkbox on the task properties dialog. I have no idea if that's the underlying problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run in elevated mode:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/

Check the box named "Run with highest privileges"

Comment: in general, how to I exec the cmd in elevated mode? `cmd.exe -admin` ?

Comment: Right click a cmd shortcut and run as admin OR right click properties -> Advanced -> the check the box "run as admin" OR check this link: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080819202757AAK2yvc

Comment: so check the link, i gave, that method it through command prompt. basically it is:  runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\YOUR-USERNAME-HERE cmd.exe